# C# and SQLite-net encrypting the database

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net

I am using [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)  in a Windows 8.1 metro app to add a SQLite database to an metro application.  It appears that I may need to encrypt the database for the application.  Does anyone know of a way to encrypt a SQLite database when using SQLite-net?  I know there are several libraries (libraries may not be the right word but.. ) like SQLcipher or SEE but not sure if/how I can use them with SQLite-net.  I am really new to C# and metro app development so I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction, I have already spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.
Thanks,

Comment: Could you explain why you want to encrypt the database? Are you sure you couldn't get away with encrypting some columns? If someone has access to the database (the user is owner of the phone) he can decrypt it. If you need to keep things secret create, keep and store them on a secured server and never let them leave it.

Comment: We are pretty sure there is going to be a requirement from our client to encrypt all data at rest.  This application will also run on a Windows tablet which will not always be connected, therefore the remote secure server is not an option for us.  Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Please note that you will not be able to secure the data. Once the secret is being read and written on the local machine it cannot not be completely safe. You should consider the data to be obscured, not secured.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Windows Data Protection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx). 
With this you can encrypt and decrypt the values with the default user credentials. [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I did see that during my research but I am unsure how to integrate it with sqlite-net.  I looked though the SQLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs classes but not sure where to put the protect/unprotect methods.